# Bash Script: Git fetch unable to fetch latest updates to remote branch

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I am writing a bash script for automatic git interaction. The issue is that once I run my script with the changes, I am able to push correctly, but on next run, git fetch does not show me the latest commits(on remote branch) which I did using the script.

I am able to see my change commit of my script on our repo(gitlab), but if I run the script again with other commit, during the fetch part, I dont see any ref updates

```
branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

If I check manually doing `git fetch origin command`, it updates the refs correctly, but the `git fetch ${_gitUrl}` does not update the refs of my remote. I am using the gitUrl constructed because I dont want a uName and password prompt, and I did not want to use ssh here.

How can I use git fetch with my https url to reliably update my remote refs? Please help.

My git push is: `git push ${_gitUrl} "${_branchToPush}:${branchName}"`

My git fetch is: `git fetch --prune "${_gitUrl}"`

I have also tried `git fetch "${_gitUrl}"`

My gitUrl is: `https://uName:pwd@repo/project.git`

My `git config --get remote.origin.fetch`
`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Checking the HEAD after fetch: `git log origin/${branchName}`

Comment: To emphasize a bit of [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305612/1256452), Git cannot update *remote-tracking names* unless there is a *remote* involved. (This is a mild overstatement but that's how the overall design works: use a remote, not a URL, to get the benefits/features introduced *by* the concept of remotes.)

Comment: @torek Yes I got that, I am trying to figure out how to use remote names in my scenario instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this. As pointer out by [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305612/8311083) that git does not map url to remotes, meaning on `git fetch ${_gitUrl}` will not update my remotes(I was assuming origin/*) will be updated.
For this to work, I mapped the remote name(origin) with the url:

```
git remote set-url origin ${_gitUrl}
git fetch ${_gitUrl}
```

This is correctly fetching the remotes from url. I dont know if this is best solution, as now the password is stored from the url and visible on `git config --list`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use git fetch with my https url to reliably update my remote refs?

What remote refs? It seems you think that `git fetch/pull/push "${_gitUrl}"` makes `git` match the URL back to remote name? No, `git` doesn't do that.

One reason is efficiency. Why spend time mapping URL to remotes?

Another reason is unambiguity. What if there are multiple remotes with the same URL? Git allows that. To what remote Git should map the URL in that case?

So no, Git doesn't do that. Name your remote yourself.

Comment: Ohh. So what should I be doing if I want to do a fetch with httpsUrl without a prompt?

Comment: @NiharGht Run `git fetch origin`, not `git fetch "${_gitUrl}"`. Or write code that maps `"${_gitUrl}"` back to remote name; a loop over remotes that compares URLs.

Comment: I found one way to make this work, but I dont know if its the best way. I am setting the remote with url as ```git remote set-url ${_remoteName} ${_gitUrl}```. A downside with this is I am storing the password here, but it seems to work.